# Twitter Insights API with Postman

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-oauth, postman

I'm trying to read insights of my Twitter account with Twitter [Insights API](https://dev.twitter.com/ads/reference/get/insights/accounts/%3Aaccount_id) and when I request to that given end point I get and error called :

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS",
            "message": "This request is not properly authenticated"
        }
    ],
    "request": {
        "params": {}
    }
}
```

This is the end point I tried :

https://ads-api.twitter.com/2/insights/accounts/:account_id/available_audiences

I used the given credentials like Consumer Key, Secret and Token, Token secret.

Can anyone explain me why I'm getting this error ? And what I should do ?

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Header:

[image]

Comment: Did you send token in headers ?

Comment: Yes I ticked that checkbox when I was doing the API call.

Comment: With Bearer + TOKEN ?

Comment: Well, I don't know that. I just fill up the header information with the details on my Twitter App

Comment: try in headers put a key: "Authorization" and a value: "Bearer "+YOURTOKEN

Comment: I checked the header. There's already a Authorization key. I updated the question with a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You have to check box "Add params to header"

Everything else should be ok. Just check Consumer Key, Consumer Secret,... data

Comment: Yes, but it will only work if the developer account is whitelisted for access to the Ads API